# Depositing Cdn$ cheques into a US bank without being charged a commission and facing a substantial hold period

Tags: foreign-exchange, check, currency, foreign

I received 2 cheques drawn on a Canadian bank account in Canadian dollars. I live in the US. I want to convert the Canadian dollars to US dollars, however to do so my US bank wants to charge a 3% commission on the entire deposit, and tells me it will take longer for these checks to clear than domestic checks. Is there any way to reduce or avoid those annoyances?

Answer (score 2):

If it's really a "commission", find another bank.

If it's a currency exchange fee, welcome to international commerce; that's really not unreasonable, I'm afraid.

Businesses which do many transactions on both sides of the US/CA border sometimes maintain bank accounts on both sides, and just hold onto the money without converting it until they need to spend it in that country. That is obviously more hassle, but it avoids some conversion costs. They may also figure this overhead into the prices they charge in each currency, passing the cost along to the consumer.

And yes, international checks -- even when the countries are adjacent and friendly -- usually take longer to clear than domestic checks. Whether it *should* still take longer, I can't say -- but again, this is standard practice and all you can do is either avoid international banking (see above) or be a bit more patient.

And yes, this means that bad-check fraud may take longer to discover when the check is not drawn on a domestic bank. Caveat vendor.